# Change vector if even/odd in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab programming and I've only had 3  classes so far. I'm having problem with my homework. (Also I am from Iceland so english is not my first language, so please forgive my grammar)
I'm given a matrix, A and I'm supposed to change the value? of a vector to 0 if it is an even number and to 1 if it is an odd number.

This is what I have so far.

```
    A = [90 100 87 43 20 58; 29 5 12 94 8 62; 75 21 36 83 35 24; 47 51 70 59 82 33]; 
    B = zeros(size(A));

    for k = 1:length(A)
        if mod(A(k),2)== 0 %%number is even
            B(k) = 0;
        else
            B(k) = 1;    %%number is odd
        end

end

B(A,2==0) = 0;
B(A,2~=0) = 1
```

What I am getting it this:

```
B =
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

If anyone could please help me, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Yes, it would be acceptable, we were just studying loops last week so I thought I could use it, but Rayryeng showed me a much simpler solution using a mod call.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  Please consider accepting my answer :) that can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon, at the top of my post to the left below the up and down arrows.  Good luck! Gangi þér vel!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close.  Don't use `length(A)` - use [`numel(A)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html).  `length(A)` returns the number of elements **along the largest dimension**.  As such, because you have 6 columns and 4 rows, this loop will only iterate 6 times.  `numel` returns the **total number of elements in the array `A`**, which is what you want as you want to iterate over each value in `A`.

Therefore:

```
A = [90 100 87 43 20 58; 29 5 12 94 8 62; 75 21 36 83 35 24; 47 51 70 59 82 33]; 
B = zeros(size(A));

for k = 1:numel(A) %// Change
    if mod(A(k),2)== 0 %%number is even
        B(k) = 0;
    else
        B(k) = 1;    %%number is odd
    end
end
```

The above loop will go through every single element in the matrix and set the corresponding element to 0 if even and 1 if odd.

However, I encourage you to use vectorized operations on your code.  Don't use loops for this.  Specifically, you can do this very easily with a single `mod` call:

```
B = mod(A,2);
```

`mod(A,2)` will compute the modulus of every value in the matrix `A` with 2 as the operand and output a matrix `B` of the same size.  This will exactly compute the parity of each number.

We get for `B`:

```
>> A = [90 100 87 43 20 58; 29 5 12 94 8 62; 75 21 36 83 35 24; 47 51 70 59 82 33]; 
>> B = mod(A,2)

B =

     0     0     1     1     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     1     1     0
     1     1     0     1     0     1
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! This worked and it's so much more simple!

Comment: @BMG Since you are a new user: don't forget to accept the answer when you can! (tick mark in the upper left corner)

Comment: Great advice!  There's rarely a reason to use `length`, unless you are intentionally demonstrating potentially buggy code.

Comment: @chappjc - One of the first lessons I learned was not using `length`.  I have you to thank for that :)!